# Spring Data JPA Specifications Calling

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I followed this tutorial to get Spring Data JPA Specifications: https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-data-jpa-specification

It worked to implement that for me, but I can't call the specifications methods to search for them. I want to have them in my SearchController:

[image: This is the project]
Code:
TelefonbuchSpecifications:

```
public static Specification<Telefonbuch> hasVorname(String vorname) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        return cb.equal(root.get(Telefonbuch_.vorname), "%"+vorname.toLowerCase()+"%");
    };
}
```

And now I want to call this method in my SearchController (SucheController), but I don't know how.
At the moment the method looks like this:
SucheController:

```
   public void search(String vorname, String nachname, String telefonnummer, String handynummer) {  
    telefonbuch.setVorname(vorname);
    telefonbuch.setNachname(nachname);
    telefonbuch.setTelefonnummer(telefonnummer);
    telefonbuch.setHandynummer(handynummer);

    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Telefonbuch> query = builder.createQuery(Telefonbuch.class);
    Root<Telefonbuch> root = query.from(Telefonbuch.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();



    if (!vorname.isEmpty()) {   
        //eintraege = telefonbuchRepository.findAll(hasVorname()); -> does not work
        Predicate condition = builder.like(builder.lower(root.get(Telefonbuch_.vorname)), "%"+vorname.toLowerCase()+"%");
        predicates.add(condition);
    }
...
query.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
```

Comment: You must use JPA repositories .Have a look at the CustomerRepository https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-data-jpa-specification

Comment: I use JPA repositories in my "TelefonbuchRepository": public interface TelefonbuchRepository extends JpaRepository<Telefonbuch, Long>

Comment: but you commented out this line. What does not work?

Comment: The method is undefined for SucheController. I can call it as TelefonbuchSpecifications.hasVorname(...) but not else. And even if i call it like this, I don't know how to use it like the predicates to have it like conditions

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a a TelefonbuchRepository interface which implements `JpaRepository` and [`JpaSpecificationExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html). The latter gives you methods, to which you can pass your `Specification`:

```
 - long     count(Specification<T> spec) 
 - List<T>  findAll(Specification<T> spec) 
 - Page<T>  findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)
 - List<T>  findAll(Specification<T> spec, Sort sort) 
 - Optional<T> findOne(Specification<T> spec)
```

Edit: MySpecification:

```
public class MyEntitySpecification implements Specification<MyEntity> {

   private final String searchText;

   public MyEntitySpecification(String searchText) {
      this.searchText = searchText;
   }

   @Override
   public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
      List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
      Optional.ofNullable(searchText).ifPresent(
         s -> predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(MyEntity_.searchString)), "%" + s.toLowerCase() + "%"))
      );
      return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
   }
}
```

Comment: Now i am calling telefonbuchRepository.findAll(TelefonbuchSpecifications.hasVorname(vorname))

but it won't give me anything

Comment: Check the underlying SQL being generated. I'all also add to my answer how i generate my `Specification`. HTH. In your first code you use cb.equal which is wrong. In your second snippet you use builder exactly like me.

Comment: Sorry but this can't be the right way. I don't know why this isn't working: https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-data-jpa-specification
I can't use the findAll method because it tells me:
The method findAll(Sort) in the type JpaRepository<Telefonbuch,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Specification<Telefonbuch>)
but why he thinks it is Sort when a Specification is given? He even shows me that there is .findAll (Specification<Telefonbuch> spec)

Comment: Can you take a look at this please? [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54950130/quiz-game-create-questions-answers-and-historical-for-admins) perhaps you can help me out.